# Precomputing inverse with unknown diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given an invertible matrix $A$. I like to compute the matrix inverse, with diagonal matrix $D$, i.e.,

$$
f(D) = (D - A)^{-1}.
$$

Is there a way to precompute something to accelerate the evaluation of function $f$ for any diagonal matrix $D$.

Comment: $D-A$ need not be invertible. Take $A=D$ for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, this is correct, but this does not prevent the computation in general.